# Use case for input[ngbdatepicker] directive

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

Attempting to intorduce the ngbDatePicker into the project, after installation and configuring the module. It just won't work with the approach I am currently taking. This is to use the input[ngbDatepicker] directive provided by bootstrap.

I have applied it to an input field with the above selector but get an error instead

`<input class="form-control" type="text" input[ngbDatepicker]>`

Actual expectation was for this to atleast work some how but instead when the directive is applied on an element, it just throws the following error:

**Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'input[ngbdatepicker]' is not a valid attribute name**.

There isn't much documentation provided on how to use this except this: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbInputDatepicker

Comment: check the examples - in the the tab "examples" you can see code, html or even check in stackblitz-  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples, e.g. `<ngb-datepicker [(ngModel)]="model" ></ngb-datepicker>

Comment: Yeah I have had a look at the examples provided via the docs

Comment: @Chief you are adding directive to the input which is not valid. The date picker has it's element `<ngb-datepicker>`

Comment: @MaihanNijat it is recommended if you want it in a popup

Comment: Try this `<input class="form-control" type="text" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">`